# TinyMCE, when i change language, editor does not appear

Tags: php, tinymce

I have a problem with tinyMCE. When i use the defaut language (english), everything works.

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    relative_urls : true,       
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    skin : "o2k7",
    width: "790",
    height: "650",
    plugins : "smarty,img,sondage,variable,autolink,questionnaire,example,fullpage,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,inlinepopups,autosave",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,|,img,questionnaire,variable,sondage,smarty",
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example word content CSS (should be your site CSS) this one removes paragraph margins
    content_css : "/com-include/cms-v1/editeur/tinymce/examples/css/word.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "/com-include/cms-v1/editeur/tinymce/examples/lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "/com-include/cms-v1/editeur/tinymce/examples/lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "/com-include/cms-v1/editeur/tinymce/examples/lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "/com-include/cms-v1/editeur/tinymce/examples/lists/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
```

But now, if i add an attribut `language : 'fr'`, the editor doesn't appear and i don't know why. I have download the language pack.

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Does JavaScript report any errors? Can you show how exactly you're adding the language?

Comment: did you place the janguage files in the correct directories?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the appropriate language file in the langs directory..